# App crashing when suegue to a uitableview after XCode 6 update

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, xcode6

I have an app I've been working on for quite some time where I have a Settings screen made out of a UITableView with fixed cells (not runtime created). After updating to XCode 6 the app crashes and sets the breakpoint to the end of the main() function when it tries to segue to the Settings page when being run on iOS 8. It works and has always worked on iOS 7 and iOS 6.

I try to debug but the crash occurs after the object that the table view is being called from finishes - "- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender" and before the tableViewController object is being created. Anyone experienced this problem before? Any suggestions for me on where to start looking?

I'm a bit baffled and lost.

Best regards
Frederik

Comment: What error did Xcode print in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by deleteing the UITableView and creating a new one in IB. No need to do a new code file. I could use the old TableViewController files with the new view.

I did notice the graphics have changed a bit since iOS7 so I assume it had a part to play in the error.